# ImageStreamTag per Git commit

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, openshift

We are running OpenShift 3.11, building container images and pushing them to the `latest` tag, overwriting the previous `latest` tag.

We do not wish to use imperative versioning such as `v.1.2.3`, but rather tag the image with the Git commit SHA, e.g. `project-name/app-name:9ff84740dd2`. That means one one new ImageStreamTag will be created for every built image on the CI server.

This however does not scale very nicely. Say you get close to 100 new changes (100 new commits). Then you will have 100 ImageStreamTags for that particular application.

The background is that we want to be able to deploy potentially different images of the same app, referencing the Git commit SHA for the particular change/commit.

Is there any operator or similar stand-alone system for Kubernetes/OpenShift that solves this? I do not wish to use GitLab, although GitLab provides this functionality (see image).

[image: gitlab-example]

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve? An image registry that is more browsable/user friendly than the default OpenShift ui with 100s of imagestreams?

Comment: @Nick As I wrote: "The background is that we want to be able to deploy potentially different images of the same app, referencing the Git commit SHA for the particular change/commit.". Furthermore, I want to be able to have 100% control over what changes are deployed and relate them to the source code checked into SCM.

Comment: If I'm understanding you your question is either:
1) How to reduce the number of container images built during development if images are built from each commit
or
2) How to deploy blue/green deployments in OpenShift (i.e. Deploy multiple instances of an application from different container image tags)

Comment: @Nick 1 is more on track. My assumption is that it will not scale. However, my particular suggested way of doing it may not be the best, so I am open for other solutions to the underlying problem. :-)

Comment: In reality you will likely only care about the last X number of image tags. You can configure [build pruning](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/builds/advanced-build-operations.html#builds-build-pruning_advanced-build-operations) and [image pruning](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/applications/pruning-objects.html#pruning-images_pruning-objects) to automatically retain only the latest X number of objects, so build to your hearts content, regardless of the commit count and only keep the last 10/30/50/etc.